# Why does Cygwin's pathnames seem to be incorrect for executables?

Tags: cygwin

I use the current version of Cygwin, 1.7.9-1.

When I typed "$ which python", Cygwin output "/usr/bin/python".

To confirm the root is the cygwin folder in my Windows 7 file system, I "cd /", and then "ls". The displayed result showed that the root is indeed the cygwin folder.

But the python executable is actually in the directory /bin. And there's no executable named "python" whatsoever in /usr/bin/python.

Why does Cygwin mistake /bin for /usr/bin? Thanks.

Update: I think my questions have been resolved. As a reference from cygwin.com, I've found this:
"/usr/bin and /usr/lib are by default also automatic mount points generated by the Cygwin DLL similar to the way the root directory is evaluated. /usr/bin points to the directory the Cygwin DLL is installed in, /usr/lib is supposed to point to the /lib directory. This choice is safe and usually shouldn't be changed."
http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html

Update: Here's another good description:
"Q: Why is C:\cygwin\usr\bin invisible from windows? A: Because it does not really exist. In cygwin, /usr/bin is just a link to /bin. E.g., if you "ls" the files in /usr/bin and in /bin, you will see identical files."
http://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/prog/cygwin/FAQs.html#usrbin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `which` outputs the path to executables which would have been executed were the command be run (i.e. executable on the `PATH`).
2. By default only `/usr/bin` is placed on the `PATH` (`/bin` being the set of essential commands). See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/difference-between-bin-and-usr-bin) for more info.
3. `/bin` (or rather `C:\path\to\cygwin\bin`) is mounted on `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Thanks, dm3. Regarding your point 3, python.exe is placed ONLY in my /bin directory but not in /usr/bin, which actually doesn't exist. Should I really believe that "Now, /bin is a symbolic link to /usr/bin: they are essentially the same directory", as written at http://rcsg-gsir.imsb-dsgi.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/documents/basic/node32.html .

Comment: Have a look at the output of the 'mount' command, where you'll see /usr/bin being mapped to C:\Cygwin\bin.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, what's the relationship between the command "mount" and "df", in your opinion?

Comment: What do you mean by a "relationship"? `df` shows the mount points as its secondary feature, while `mount` does it for a living. Did that answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Nice description. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, your Cygwin setup must be different than mine.

On my system, /usr/bin and /bin are actually the same directory; `df` shows that `C:/cygwin/bin` is actually mounted as `/usr/bin`.  So of course `/bin/python.exe` and `/usr/bin/python.exe` exist and are the same file (which can also be referred to as `/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python`).

How up to date is your Cygwin?  Are you *sure* there's no `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/python.exe`?

Comment: Well, thanks a lot. The mounting thing looks a little confusing to me. Indeed, I "ls /usr/bin", there's a python.exe . Before I posted this question on stackoverflow.com , I simply had only looked into the Windows Explorer provided by Windows 7, and there's no python.exe in the /usr/bin directory there. It seems that Windows 7 doesn't recognized that sort of mounting happening in Cygwin. Thanks.

Comment: But I still don't get why Cygwin takes the hassle of mounting /bin onto /usr/bin. From what I can see, there's no need for that, just put binaries into either of them. Maybe that arrangement has something to do with the requirements of UNIX, which Cygwin is built upon.

Comment: @alex_wang: I think the point is that the choice of which applications should be in /bin and which should be in /usr/bin is fairly arbitrary.  Making /bin and /usr/bin the same directory means that (at least as seem from a Cygwin process) commands are visible in both places, which can make some thing simpler (`#!` lines, for example).